Connman connecting to eduroam (ieee8021x), but internet access only lasts for a few seconds if at all
I'm running artixlinux with connman and wpa supplicant. I've never had any issues with other wifi networks. I can successfully connect to the wifi, and connman says 'Online' -but this only lasts for a few seconds - sometimes there's no internet at all.
Below is the contents of /var/lib/connman/eduroam.config (I've taken the connman configuration from this archwiki page and I got the certificate file from the eduroam CAT):
[service_eduroam]
Type=wifi
Name=eduroam
EAP=peap
CACertFile=/etc/ssl/certs/Nottingham.pem
Phase2=MSCHAPV2
Identity=someone@nottingham.ac.uk
Passphrase=pass

Sidenote - the eduroam CAT also generates a wpa_supplicant config file which looks like this:
network={
  ssid="eduroam"
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  eap=PEAP
  ca_cert="/home/user/.config/cat_installer/ca.pem"
  identity="someone@nottingham.ac.uk"
  altsubject_match="DNS:radius.nottingham.ac.uk"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  password="pass"
}

UPDATE - just figured it's probably a DNS issue because running ping 1.1.1.1 works. My /etc/resolv.conf looks like this:
# Generated by dhcpcd from wlan0.dhcp
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
domain nottingham.ac.uk
nameserver 128.243.46.11
nameserver 128.243.42.5
nameserver 128.243.46.12
nameserver 128.243.42.6
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line


A temporary fix is adding nameserver 1.1.1.1 to /etc/resolv.conf.head
